# Wordpress get user by date returns empty list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a function that lists all the users that registered today but for some reason it returns an empty result

```
function get_user_by_date($start=null,$end=null){
          global $wpdb;
          if ($start == null && $end == null){
              $end = date("Y-m-d");
          }
          echo $end;
          $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_registered >= %s";
          $prep = $wpdb->prepare($query,$end);
  echo $prep;     
          $results = $wpdb->get_results($prep);
          return $results;
      }
```

Query looks like this when I tried to echo prepared statement

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_registered >= '2015-02-27'
```

When I use this query in my PHPMyAdmin, it works fine. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling the function? You've got some null checks in there that might be preventing a valid `$end` from being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_registered >= DATETIME(%s)";
```

and here:

```
 $end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: but do you have any user registered today or tomorrow? in your data table?

Comment: and you are right. I was running query in my live server.